# cucumber testing for checking parent of an element with certain class

Tags: cucumber, css-selectors, bdd

I have an element with id: `#post` and that element has parent `<li>`. Now I want to check whether the `<li>` has class `.current` or not.
The step might be like

```
Then the element "post" with parent "li" should have class "current"
```

If any body could help me with step_definitions, that'll be gr8!

Comment: What gem are you using to drive the browser?  Also, could you provide the snippet of html that contains the <li> and it's children?

Comment: I am using capybara. It is sth like this: <li class="current"><a href="post.html" id="post"> Post</a></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this, (which works):

```
Then /^"([^\"]*)" should have class "([^\"]*)"$/ do |id, parent_class|
  assert page.has_xpath?('//a[@id="'+id+'"]/..[@class="'+parent_class+'"]')
end
```

Answer (score 4):

With webrat you can search for an css selector. Maybe this solves your problem:

```
Then the element "([^"]*)" with parent "([^"]*)" should have class "([^"]*)" do |element_id,parent,css_class|
  response.should have_selector "#{parent} .#{css_class}" do |matches|
    matches.should have_selector element_id
  end
end
```

I didn't try this code, but it should work for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

These suggestions should work for you, but you might also want to consider decoupling your selectors from your stories to make your test suite easier to maintain, and more expressive of business value. Eg: you might change the step to something like:

```
Then the post should be displayed as the current post
```

This becomes pretty easy to implement if you're using [Pickle](http://railscasts.com/episodes/186-pickle-with-cucumber):

```
# /features/posts/viewing.feature
Given the following posts exist:
  | post  | title             | slug              |
  | Lorem | Lorem Ipsum Dolor | lorem-ispum-dolor |
  | Hello | Hello World       | hello-world       |
When I go to the post page for post "Hello"
Then post "Hello" should be displayed as the current post

# /features/step_definitions/post_steps.rb
Then /^#{capture_model} should be displayed as the current post$/ do |post_reference|
  post = model!(post_reference)
  page.should have_css("li.current ##{dom_id(post)}")
end
```